# Draw random day of the month depending on the month of the year

Tags: r, date, random

I want to generate random day of the month depending on the month of the year. My current code is:

```
  df$new_day = case_when(
  df$new_month == 2 ~ (floor(runif(1, min=1, max=28))),
  df$new_month == 1 ~ floor(runif(1, min=1, max=31)),
  df$new_month == 3 ~ floor(runif(1, min=1, max=31)),
  df$new_month == 5 ~ floor(runif(1, min=1, max=31)),
  df$new_month == 7 ~ floor(runif(1, min=1, max=31)),
  df$new_month == 8 ~ floor(runif(1, min=1, max=31)),
  df$new_month == 10 ~ floor(runif(1, min=1, max=31)),
  df$new_month == 12 ~ floor(runif(1, min=1, max=31)),
  TRUE ~ floor(runif(1, min=1, max=30))
)
```

However, my day for a given month is all the same. For instance, all the dates for Feb will be 23.

How can I truly randomize the date within each month?

Answer (score 5):

You are explicitly calling for 1 random number each time: `runif(1, ...)`. Instead, use `runif(n(), ...)`. Realize that it isn't called once for each row, it is run once for all rows that meet that condition. In my example below, there are three rows in May, but `runif` is called as `runif(1,..)` and that single number is applied to all three rows.

Sample data:

```r
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(day = as.Date("2022-01-01") + sample(364, size=10)) %>%
  arrange(day) %>%
  mutate(month = as.POSIXlt(day)$mon + 1L)
df
#           day month
# 1  2022-02-19     2
# 2  2022-03-16     3
# 3  2022-05-03     5
# 4  2022-05-09     5
# 5  2022-05-27     5
# 6  2022-06-03     6
# 7  2022-08-17     8
# 8  2022-10-31    10
# 9  2022-11-18    11
# 10 2022-12-31    12
```

Broken:

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)
df %>%
  mutate(
    new_day = case_when(
      month == 2                ~ floor(runif(1, 1, 28)), 
      month %in% c(9, 4, 6, 11) ~ floor(runif(1, 1, 30)), 
      TRUE                      ~ floor(runif(1, 1, 31))
    )
  )
#           day month new_day
# 1  2022-02-19     2      25
# 2  2022-03-16     3       9
# 3  2022-05-03     5       9
# 4  2022-05-09     5       9
# 5  2022-05-27     5       9
# 6  2022-06-03     6      28
# 7  2022-08-17     8       9
# 8  2022-10-31    10       9
# 9  2022-11-18    11      28
# 10 2022-12-31    12       9
```

To demonstrate that `runif` is being called *once* for all rows that meet each criterion, I'll add `message` to each. If we could rely on `runif(1,..)`, then we should see `"30d"` printed to the console 7 times and `"31d"` twice, but we don't.

```r
set.seed(42)
df %>%
  mutate(
    new_day = case_when(
      month == 2                ~ { message("Feb: ", length(month)); floor(runif(1, 1, 28)); }, 
      month %in% c(9, 4, 6, 11) ~ { message("30d: ", length(month)); floor(runif(1, 1, 30)); }, 
      TRUE                      ~ { message("31d: ", length(month)); floor(runif(1, 1, 31)); }
    )
  )
# Feb: 10
# 30d: 10
# 31d: 10
#           day month new_day
# 1  2022-02-19     2      25
# 2  2022-03-16     3       9
# 3  2022-05-03     5       9
# 4  2022-05-09     5       9
# 5  2022-05-27     5       9
# 6  2022-06-03     6      28
# 7  2022-08-17     8       9
# 8  2022-10-31    10       9
# 9  2022-11-18    11      28
# 10 2022-12-31    12       9
```

This demonstrates that when we're 'inside' the RHS of one of the conditions, it is a call for all rows of the frame. Notice that each time we call `runif`, it sees *all* values of `month` (we have 10 rows in `df`).

---

Instead, use `n()` (number of rows in each call):

```r
set.seed(42)
df %>%
  mutate(
    new_day = case_when(
      month == 2                ~ floor(runif(n(), 1, 28)), 
      month %in% c(9, 4, 6, 11) ~ floor(runif(n(), 1, 30)), 
      TRUE                      ~ floor(runif(n(), 1, 31))
    )
  )
#           day month new_day
# 1  2022-02-19     2      25
# 2  2022-03-16     3       5
# 3  2022-05-03     5      30
# 4  2022-05-09     5      29
# 5  2022-05-27     5       3
# 6  2022-06-03     6      28
# 7  2022-08-17     8      12
# 8  2022-10-31    10      28
# 9  2022-11-18    11      14
# 10 2022-12-31    12      26
```

This means that we pull 30 random numbers in this `case_when`, 10 for each condition. While this is not a concern *here* (large draws on entropy can be slow), you can mitigate by pre-pulling random data and then scaling accordingly.

```r
set.seed(42)
df %>%
  mutate(
    rand = runif(n(), 0, 1),
    new_day = case_when(
      month == 2                ~ ceiling(rand*28), 
      month %in% c(9, 4, 6, 11) ~ ceiling(rand*30), 
      TRUE                      ~ ceiling(rand*31)
    )
  )
#           day month      rand new_day
# 1  2022-02-19     2 0.9148060      26
# 2  2022-03-16     3 0.9370754      30
# 3  2022-05-03     5 0.2861395       9
# 4  2022-05-09     5 0.8304476      26
# 5  2022-05-27     5 0.6417455      20
# 6  2022-06-03     6 0.5190959      16
# 7  2022-08-17     8 0.7365883      23
# 8  2022-10-31    10 0.1346666       5
# 9  2022-11-18    11 0.6569923      20
# 10 2022-12-31    12 0.7050648      22
```

(noting the shift from `floor` to `ceiling`). There are further ways the code can be refactored, but I think this is generally good-enough.

Comment: Oh wow I've learned so much from this. Thank you!!!

Comment: See my edit, one more suggestion to reduce over-pulling from entropy. Generally not a problem, especially with a dataset this small, but if your real code gets "large" then reducing over-pulling random numbers might help performance ... and if you have other code that gets more expensive, this may indeed help, removing expensive code from unlikely `case_when`-conditions.

Comment: Appreciate that. My dataset is 1GB so not a problem this time but I ran into similar problem in the past with large datasets (20Gb+) so definitely appreciating your edits.

Comment: As a side-thought, since you have larger data: consider replacing your `case_when` with `left_join(., data.frame(month=1:12, ndays=c(31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31)), by="month") %>% mutate(new_day = ceiling(rand*ndays))`. This might perform better, I haven't benchmarked it. FYI, this is still prone to leap-year issues; it's not hard to counter that, but it'll be another call or two.

Comment: A half decimal needs to be added to the minimum and maximum days, otherwise the rounding will mean that the first and last days are under-represented, e.g., `runif(n(), 0.5, 28.5)`

Answer (score 1):

`sampl`ing from a `seq.Date` call that exploits values stored in `POSIXlt`. We may easily substitute days and increment the month (but subtract one day). This automatically takes into account the **leap years etc.**

```
f <- \(x) {
  sample(with(as.POSIXlt(x),
              seq.Date(as.Date(ISOdate(year + 1900, mon + 1, 1, 0)),
                       as.Date(ISOdate(year + 1900, mon + 2, 1, 0)) - 1, 'day')),
         1)
}

res <- transform(df, new_date=do.call(c, lapply(df$date, f)))
res
#            x       date   new_date
# 1  0.9148060 2021-06-17 2021-06-22
# 2  0.9370754 2022-08-13 2022-08-18
# 3  0.2861395 2020-08-23 2020-08-13
# 4  0.8304476 2022-07-30 2022-07-28
# 5  0.6417455 2021-07-20 2021-07-05
# 6  0.5190959 2021-09-23 2021-09-04
# 7  0.7365883 2020-09-12 2020-09-02
# 8  0.1346666 2022-05-20 2022-05-24
# 9  0.6569923 2021-05-09 2021-05-18
# 10 0.7050648 2019-09-16 2019-09-03
# 11 0.4577418 2022-08-30 2022-08-24
# 12 0.7191123 2020-04-25 2020-04-23
# 13 0.9346722 2022-08-14 2022-08-17
# 14 0.2554288 2019-01-24 2019-01-21
# 15 0.4622928 2022-03-27 2022-03-26
# 16 0.9400145 2019-10-26 2019-10-18
# 17 0.9782264 2020-02-10 2020-02-06
# 18 0.1174874 2019-11-10 2019-11-06
# 19 0.4749971 2022-08-08 2022-08-02
# 20 0.5603327 2021-04-15 2021-04-20
```

Not really sure though if you want dates or numbers. If you want new months and days to be displayed as numbers you may do

```
within(res, {
  new_date <- do.call(c, lapply(df$date, f))
  month <- strftime(new_date, '%m')
  day <- strftime(new_date, '%d')
  }) |>
  type.convert(as.is=TRUE)
#            x       date   new_date day month
# 1  0.9148060 2021-06-17 2021-06-03   3     6
# 2  0.9370754 2022-08-13 2022-08-22  22     8
# 3  0.2861395 2020-08-23 2020-08-21  21     8
# 4  0.8304476 2022-07-30 2022-07-02   2     7
# 5  0.6417455 2021-07-20 2021-07-23  23     7
# 6  0.5190959 2021-09-23 2021-09-06   6     9
# 7  0.7365883 2020-09-12 2020-09-26  26     9
# 8  0.1346666 2022-05-20 2022-05-10  10     5
# 9  0.6569923 2021-05-09 2021-05-08   8     5
# 10 0.7050648 2019-09-16 2019-09-05   5     9
# 11 0.4577418 2022-08-30 2022-08-01   1     8
# 12 0.7191123 2020-04-25 2020-04-17  17     4
# 13 0.9346722 2022-08-14 2022-08-07   7     8
# 14 0.2554288 2019-01-24 2019-01-04   4     1
# 15 0.4622928 2022-03-27 2022-03-13  13     3
# 16 0.9400145 2019-10-26 2019-10-10  10    10
# 17 0.9782264 2020-02-10 2020-02-09   9     2
# 18 0.1174874 2019-11-10 2019-11-29  29    11
# 19 0.4749971 2022-08-08 2022-08-12  12     8
# 20 0.5603327 2021-04-15 2021-04-20  20     4
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(0.914806043496355, 0.937075413297862, 0.286139534786344, 
0.830447626067325, 0.641745518893003, 0.519095949130133, 0.736588314641267, 
0.13466659723781, 0.656992290401831, 0.705064784036949, 0.45774177624844, 
0.719112251652405, 0.934672247152776, 0.255428824340925, 0.462292822543532, 
0.940014522755519, 0.978226428385824, 0.117487361654639, 0.474997081561014, 
0.560332746244967), date = structure(c(18795, 19217, 18497, 19203, 
18828, 18893, 18517, 19132, 18756, 18155, 19234, 18377, 19218, 
17920, 19078, 18195, 18302, 18210, 19212, 18732), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a little helper function which will return the number of day for each month.

```
month_days <- function(x) case_when(
  x == 2 ~ 28,
  x %in% c(1,3,5,7,8,10) ~ 31,
  TRUE ~ 30
)
```

Then you can use the fact that `max=` is vectorized in `runif` to get all the values at once. Noce that since you are doing `floor()` you'll want to add 1 to the max so you have a chance of observing that value

```
set.seed(22)
# test data
N <- 50
dd <- data.frame(new_month = sample(1:12, N, replace=TRUE))

dd$new_day <- floor( runif( length(dd$new_month), min=1, max=month_days(dd$new_month) + 1 ) )
```